# Find all solutions of the given equation $\sec^2 θ − 4 = 0$. Let $k$ be any integer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all solutions of the given equation:
>   $$\sec^2 θ − 4 = 0$$

My answer is $\pi/4 + πk$ and $-pi/4 + πk$.

Comment: So what is your question, then? If you just want to check the answers, WolframAlpha can do it.\

Comment: Does it cost money?

Comment: @user137452 : For most applications, no.

Answer (score 1):

This gives: $(\sec\theta - 2)(\sec\theta + 2) = 0$. So: $\sec\theta = \pm 2$, or $\cos\theta = \pm\dfrac{1}{2}$. Thus: $\theta = \pm \dfrac{\pi}{3} + n\pi$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Perhaps the promise of an upvote could persuade you to rephrase the answer as $\theta = n\pi \pm \frac{\pi}{3}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?  Okay, I'll give my upvote anyway...

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{\cos^2(\theta)}=4\quad\Rightarrow\quad\frac{1}{4}=\cos^2(\theta)$$
$$\cos(\theta)=\pm\frac{1}{2}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\pm\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$\therefore\quad\theta\in\left\{\frac{\pi}{3}\left(1+n\,,\;2+n\,,\;4+n\,,\;5+n\;\right)\big|\; \frac{n}{6}\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

Comment: In fact, you're missing half the solutions : $y^2 = \frac 14$ means $y \in \{-1/2,1/2\}$.

Comment: I know but my computer crashed before I could edit it!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we have  squares of trigonometric ratios, convert to double angle of cosine.

$$\cos^2\theta=\frac12\implies\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1=0\implies 2\theta=(2n+1)\frac\pi2$$ where $n$ is any integer